# Load value to mat-select component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with 2 way binding in mat-select component (angular material).
In my ts file I have a option list and the binding variable (valueFromDB).
Then I select value in mat-select component it's copy the value to valueFromDB variable. On another hand, On sceen load I would like to see in my mat-select component valueFromDB variable. How can I do it?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grupfc?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html

```
export class SelectValueBindingExample {
  valueFromDB = new Option('Option2');
  options = [new Option('Option1'), new Option('Option2'), new Option('Option3')];
}

export class Option{
  name:string;
  constructor(n:string){
    this.name = n;
  }
}

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="valueFromDB" >
        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor='let option of options' [value]='option' >{{option.name}}</mat-option>

    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `valueFromDB` has no reference to the objects in your array, therefore Angular cannot bind them. I see two options, create a reference by finding the matching value in the array, like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.valueFromDB = this.options.find(x => x.name === this.valueFromDB.name)
}
```

or then use `compareWith`:

```
compareFn(op1: Option, op2: Option) {
  return op1.name === op2.name;
}
```

and in template:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="valueFromDB" [compareWith]="compareFn">
```

Your StackBlitz with `compareWith`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grupfc-yjl58l?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html (creating the object reference is also added but commented out)